# Prove that $a\in G $ where $G$ is finite group with identity, then there exist $n\in Z^{+}$such that $a^{n}=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Please check my proof
Suppose G is finite group with identity $e$,and no $n\in Z^{+}$ such that $a^{n}=e$
If it is,the order of the group must be infinite, but the group is finite. It can't have element with order infinite.Therefore it must exist $n\in Z^{+}$such  that $a^{n}=e$

Comment: you really need to expand on this. For example, you need to invoke the existence of inverses at some point.

Comment: "There cannot be an element of infinite order" is just a rephrasing of what you want to prove. It isn't _immediate_ that there is an $n$ such that $a^n=e$. What you can immediately say, however, is that all the possible $a^n$ cannot be different.

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned by Tobias](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035586/prove-that-a-in-g-where-g-is-finite-group-with-identity-then-there-exist-n#comment4178652_2035586), you need more detail. See if this analogy helps:

> **Similar Problem:** If I have a solved Rubik's cube, then for any sequence of moves $a$, if I repeat the sequence $a$ enough times, then the Rubik's cube will eventually return to its solved state.

**Proof:** Let $a^n$ denote the configuration of the Rubik's cube after repeating $a$ a total of $n$ times. Consider the configurations:
$$
a, a^2, a^3, \ldots
$$

Since there are only finitely many configurations of a Rubik's cube, the above sequence must eventually repeat. Say, $a^i = a^j$ for some $i < j$. But if we undo our sequence of moves $i$ times for both configurations in this equation, we find that $a^{j - i}$ must be the solved state, as desired.